# Is faith being built on 'mind, heart and actions'?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah

I've found this [article](https://www.lookstein.org/professional-dev/faith-and-doubt/) online and part of it - from the words: "*Philosophers of religion have observed that the word 'faith' covers a number of types or categories of religious existence...*" till "*There are, then, three types of faith or, better, three manifestations of faith...*" -  is related to this question I have.

The article talks about three types of faith or, better, three manifestations of faith, namely: 1. the cognitive form/element/part of faith, 2. the affective form/element/part of faith and 3. the functional form/element/part of faith.

Now, there was a time in which people used to serve a lot of different and various gods, but then there was Avraham, his nickname; 'the father of Judiasm'. Looking at the way Avraham (the steps he took by which he) established his faith it seems to start with (the recognition) knowing and acknowledging G-d (that He exists) , which could be the cognitive form of his faith. Next Avraham seems to accept G-d as His G-d, which could be the affective form of his faith, and from hence forward he commits himself to the ways of G-d (he shows obedience to the will/voice/words of G-d).

To sum things up we have 'acknowledgement, relationship and actions' seem to be the steps of faith here. Looking at the covenant making with the people of Israël, one could say the covenant exists of 'a agreement, a bond (relationship), and actions'.

So it seems that faith is being built on:'mind, heart and actions'.

Do these elements form the foundation of what we would call faith? 
Are there any commentators which teach us about the steps/elements of faith?

Comment: Do you specifically look for interpreters that mention those 3 parts? Who is that different from any other belief - "I believe Moses is a good plumber - I know he fixes things, I appreciate his work and I call him when in need!"

Comment: I don't think we should learn about faith from non-Jewish philosophers. I would like to vote to close as "comparative religion" but I think you're asking genuinely; just not from the right angle.

Comment: @AlBerko I'm trying to figure out the elements/parts/steps/phases, there could be more as 3, and maybe it doesn't differ from any other believe. I don't know what the interpreters/commentators say about it. I'm just trying to see if there is a way to define the layers upon which our faith is built upon.